Troubleshooting File Upload Issues and Database Connection Errors for a Node.js API Deployed on Google App Engine, But Work in localhost
I created an API on my local computer that is connected to GCP services and runs perfectly. However, when I deploy it on App Engine, I encounter an error whenever I use a POST method that includes a file. other method without involving file is somehow working fine.
in my logs it shows this error :

db=postgres,user=postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

idk why... its running perfectly in my local, but not when deployed
is it related to app.yaml?
runtime: nodejs18
env: standard
instance_class: F1

env_variables:
  API_KEY: <MY_API_KEY>
  PORT: 5000
  CONNECTION_STRING: postgres://postgres:<my_password>@<instance_public_ip>:5432/<DB_NAME>
  FIREBASE_API_KEY: <FIREBASE_API>
  FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: <PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com
  FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: <PROJECT_ID>
  FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: <PROJECT_ID>.appspot.com
  FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: <MESSAGE_SENDER_ID>
  FIREBASE_APP_ID: <FIREBASE APP ID>
  MEASUREMENT_ID: <MEASUREMENT_ID>
  PROJECT_ID: <PROJECT_ID>
  BUCKET_NAME: <MY_BUCKER_NAME>

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto

I'VE BEEN WORKING ON IT FOR DAYS. thank you.

Are you sure the password you use is the correct one for both environments? Have you tried logging in to Postgres on App Engine using the credentials? Check for username, password, port, database name.

Since it's giving you a password error, that suggests your issue is with password and not with whether you're using a file or not in your POST method. Confirm your passwords are correct and/or you aren't modifying it from somewhere in your code

If you are using cloudSQL for postgresql, this could be due to either you are using wrong password or the default admin user postgres is created but not the password as mentioned here. To verify that try to connect to postgres using gcloud sql connect myinstance --user=postgres.

@AndiM.FadhilulAsyamHafid Have you managed to check above comment? Does it help you solve your issue? Or have you found any other solution?
